# awk - Processing file with Header, Sub-headers and Records

Tags: awk

I have a data file which has the following format:

```
Header:H1
Sub-header:H1S1
Record:R1
Record:R2
Sub-header:H1S2
Record:R5
Record:R6
Sub-header:H1S3
Record:R9
Record:R10
Header:H2
Sub-header:H2S1
Record:R15
Record:R16
Header:H3
Sub-header:H3S1
Record:R25
Record:R26
Sub-header:H3S2
Record:R30
Record:R31
```

I want to process this using AWK such that the file has following format:

```
H1, H1S1, R1
H1, H1S1, R2
H1, H1S2, R5
H1, H1S2, R6
H1, H1S3, R9
H1, H1S3, R10
H2, H2S1, R15
H2, H2S1, R16
H3, H3S1, R25
H3, H3S1, R26
H3, H3S2, R30
H3, H3S2, R31
```

How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you edit your post to describe what you tried, and where you faced problems? Also, do you _need_ the extra whitespace after each `,` in the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remember the header and subheader when you see them, and then print them (along with with record data) when you see a Record: line.

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=", " '/^Header:/     { header    = $2; next };
                       /^Sub-header:/ { subheader = $2; next };
                       /^Record:/     { print header, subheader, $2 }' input.txt 
H1, H1S1, R1
H1, H1S1, R2
H1, H1S2, R5
H1, H1S2, R6
H1, H1S3, R9
H1, H1S3, R10
H2, H2S1, R15
H2, H2S1, R16
H3, H3S1, R25
H3, H3S1, R26
H3, H3S2, R30
H3, H3S2, R31
```

The `next` statements are a minor optimisation - since we don't *need* anything else from the current line once we've extracted $2 from it, skip to the next line of input and start processing again from the top of the script.

For a script like this, it'll make little (if any) difference in performance - it's not doing a lot.  For more complicated scripts, perhaps with lots of patterns to match or calculations to make, it can make a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are no spaces around the `:` in your input file, the following `awk` program will do the task:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";OFS=","} $1=="Header"{h=$2} $1=="Sub-header"{s=$2} $1=="Record" {print h,s,$2}' input.txt
```

This will first set `:` as field separator for input, and `,` as field separator for output.

It will then read store the latest header and sub-header in variables `h` and `s`, respectively, every time the first input field is named `Header` and `Sub-header`, respectively. If it encounters a `Record` line, it will print the field value along with the values stored in `h` and `s`, respectively.

Note that this assumes that there is always a `Sub-header` before the first `Record`. If you want to allow for empty sub-headers, change the first rule block from

```
$1=="Header"{h=$2}
```

to

```
$1=="Header"{h=$2;s=""}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have tag-value pairs in your input as you do I find it best to first create an array to store that mapping (`f[]` below) and then you can just access/print/compare/modify/whatever the values by addressing them by their tags (names):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS=", " }
{ f[$1] = $2 }
/^Record/ { print f["Header"], f["Sub-header"], $2 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
H1, H1S1, R1
H1, H1S1, R2
H1, H1S2, R5
H1, H1S2, R6
H1, H1S3, R9
H1, H1S3, R10
H2, H2S1, R15
H2, H2S1, R16
H3, H3S1, R25
H3, H3S1, R26
H3, H3S2, R30
H3, H3S2, R31
```